# I can't seem to get multiprocessing to work on my laptop

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, multiprocessing

this is my first time posting on stackoverflow, so I hope I do not mess it up.

I am a beginner in Python, and I wanted to attempt Multi-processing. But I've spent two days following basic tutorials about it, and none of them seem to work the way I want it to. An example of what I'm trying:

```
import os

from multiprocessing import Process, current_process

def square(number):
    result = number * number

    proc_id = os.getpid()
    print(f"Process ID: {proc_id}")

    process_name = current_process().name
    print(f"Process Name: {process_name}")

    print(f"The number {number} squares to {result}.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    processes = []
    numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    for i, number in enumerate(numbers):
        process = Process(target=square, args=(number,))
        processes.append(process)

        process.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

A simple code, but all that comes out on the compiler is blank.

Yet if I change this line here:

`process = Process(target=square, args=(number,))`

To:

`process = Process(target=square(number))`

It works now! But the output would then be wrong.

**My ideal output**

```
    Process ID: 10000
    
    Process Name: Process - 1
    
    The number 1 squares to 1.
    
    
    
    Process ID: 10001
    
    Process Name: Process - 2
    
    The number 2 squares to 4.
    
    
    
    Process ID: 10002
    
    Process Name: Process - 3
    
    The number 3 squares to 9.
    
    
    
    Process ID: 10003
    
    Process Name: Process - 4
    
    The number 4 squares to 16.
```

**Actual output**

```
Process ID: 10000

Process Name: MainProcess

The number 1 squares to 1.



Process ID: 10000

Process Name: MainProcess

The number 2 squares to 4.



Process ID: 10000

Process Name: MainProcess

The number 3 squares to 9.



Process ID: 10000

Process Name: MainProcess

The number 4 squares to 16.
```

I'm using Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019, Python 3.7.

I'm not sure if the solution is simple, but my brain is square and I need help.

Comment: Your workload is so tiny that it is finished beforeca new process is started. Give it some real work to do!

Comment: I recommend that you read about Global interpreter Lock in python. It could be reason why you are getting this output.

Comment: @KlausD. I would agree with you, except this code is an example that I followed from this Youtube video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RR4SoktDQAw&t=1s) and it worked fine on the video. It's the same workload, that's why I'm still very doubtful.

Comment: Your main code is correct. `process = Process(target=square(number))` is not correct because it calls the function before the process is created.

Comment: I would look into any reason why multiprocessing is defaulting back to threads.

Comment: Your program worked for me. I got Process-1 thorugh 5 but not in that order of course. Is the problem that you didn't get any output or that you didn't like the output somehow?

Comment: @KlausD. - The joins guarantee that the parent process does not execute until the subprocesses are complete.

Comment: @Aaron I thought so, but an output actually comes out if I did 'process = Process(target=square(number))' instead. 

'process = Process(target=square, args=(number,))' when runned showed nothing.

Comment: @HariKrishnan - I don't see how the GIL would change anything here. Care to elaborate?

Comment: How are you running the program? Are you on the command line, clicking an icon or perhaps running via an IDE? I suggest running it from the command line and reporting what you see.

Comment: @tdelaney You got my ideal output, but my actual output is MainProcess only. I'm trying to figure out why that is so.

Comment: It's probably the IDE not collecting the printing (stdout) from other processes.  Run the code in a simple cmd.exe window.

Comment: ^^ this is particularly important with multiprocessing as well as gui development occasionally. For my part, I use Spyder IDE, but the run settings are always to execute in an external terminal.

Comment: @tdelaney Just tried doing what you suggested by running it on the command line, but I still got the same output. Nothing changed. :P

Comment: That's unfortunate! I was sure it was what @MarkTolonen and KickAxx suggest. Unfortunately I don't have my widows machine up at the moment.

Comment: @tdelaney What did you use to run the code though? Maybe there's an answer for me there.

Comment: Your solution `process = Process(target=square(number))` simply called `square(number)` in the parent process and tried to create a subprocess with the resulting value. Definitely not a solution!

Comment: I'm running linux. You windows command line should also work, so I'm puzzled. I assume you had a cmd.exe window open and ran `python myscript.py`. `pythonw` might be weird as it starts a new window.

Comment: Since I don't have windows running I can't test.

Comment: @tdelaney YOU ARE RIGHT! I tried using `process = Process(target=square, args=(number,))` on the cmd line instead and it works! Thank you so much, you really helped me out!

Comment: @tdelaney I should not have been using `process = Process(target=square(number))`, now I know how to solve this problem in the future.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a `multiprocessing.Process` the subprocess inherits the parent's `stdout` and can write to it. The problem is, that stdout may not being going anywhere you can read it. When you run from a GUI like an IDE, stdout is usually redirected to oblivion. An IDE instruments the running process to grab its writes to `sys.stdout` and redirect to is command output window, but that doesn't flow down to the subprocess.

Unfortunately there isn't an easy way to grab the stdout stream in a `multiprocessin.Process`. Its easy when you just execute a different program through something like `subprocess`.

The good news is that its rare for a subprocess to want to write to stdout in the first place. `multiprocessing` has several options such as `Queue` and `Pipe` to get things back to the parent process.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite the question you asked, but I strongly recommend you use `multiprocessing.Pool` whenever possible.  It saves you a lot of headache and bookkeeping.  Your entire `__main__` would be

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(square, numbers)
```